# Setting the Classpath in (Eclipse's) Jar File

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar

I have a program.jar file which includes some external libraries. Additionally I wan't to start some classes with the program.jar.

The classes (TestKlass.class,...) are located in `<path>/bin/data/test` + sometimes there will be new classes added here.

How can I set this location for the classpath so I can use this command in the jar file:

```
cStart = Class.forName("data.test.TestKlass.class");
```

This is how my current MANIFEST.MF looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ junit-4.10.jar selenium-java-2.20.0.jar WinRegistr
 y-4.4.jar selenium-server.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: data.Testworks
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

(Everything works fine within eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference external <strike>jars</strike> classes in a runnable jar file. Everything must be contained inside the jar.

Comment: I wan't to include the <path>/bin in the MANIFEST.MF as a classpath folder where class files are stored so that the program.jar can load them.

Comment: That's exactly the problem you have; you can't. All *.class files must be internal to the `program.jar` file.

Comment: Can I compile classes with JavaCompiler within the program.jar so they are stored within the program then?

Comment: Yes. In Eclipse, I have an ant task that bundles up all of my external references into my deliverable jar file. Right-click on the project and choose Export/Runnable Jar File.

Comment: What? Yes you can. His Class-Path is incorrect. It needs to be the full Classpath including the .JAR filenames relative to where he is going to be running the JAR. I have done this many times in the past.